shared extra-hosts options for docker-compose
Is there a way to set block of extra-hosts for all services in docker-compose file?
Or I should add them to each service?
serivces:
  my_service1:

    extra_hosts: 
      host1: 1.2.3.4
      host2: 5.6.7.8
...

or maybe way to set it as variable list and use .env for example
I want to use one block of extra hosts for all services in docker compose file.

Why do you need this option?  Do you have a local DNS server that provides these host names?

I need my services to resolve each over (and some over hosts) fqdns for proper work of ssl connections.
Don't want to setup dns server for this...

A quick test showed that the --add-host option modifies the /etc/hosts file in the container. You might try experimenting with mapping a shared hosts file onto that path in all your containers.

yeah, I've got this as an option.
for now I think I'll use anchors like this
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/10-fragments/

You can use https://docs.docker.com/reference/compose-file/extension/.
version: '3'
x-hosts: &default-hosts
  extra_hosts:
    - "host1.local:127.0.0.1"
    - "host2.local:127.0.0.1"

services:
  my_service1:
    image: "service1:latest"
    restart: always
    <<: *default-hosts
    network_mode: 'host'

  my_service2:
    image: "service1:latest"
    restart: always
    <<: *default-hosts
    network_mode: 'host'
...

Even you can use .env to share extra_hosts between mulitiple compose file.
.env:
HOST1_IP=127.0.01
HOST2_IP=127.0.01

compose1.yaml:
version: '3'
x-hosts: &default-hosts
  extra_hosts:
    - "host1.local:${HOST1_IP}"
    - "host2.local:${HOST2_IP}"
services:
  my_service1:
    image: "service1:latest"
    restart: always
    <<: *default-hosts
    network_mode: 'host'

compose2.yaml:
version: '3'
x-hosts: &default-hosts
  extra_hosts:
    - "host1.local:${HOST1_IP}"
    - "host2.local:${HOST2_IP}"
services:
  my_service2:
    image: "service2:latest"
    restart: always
    <<: *default-hosts
    network_mode: 'host'


